# What is the command to get my System Inormation?

Tags: system-info

A command which can display RAM size, processor, graphics card, Disk size, OS (32 or 64)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`dmidecode`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/dmidecode.8.html) command.